# When to use lib.es2015.d.ts vs @types/core-js?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

It seems `lib.es2015.d.ts` that ships with the Typescript compiler conflicts with the `@types/core-js` package if they are both being referenced.

[This post](http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/03/28/ambient-type-definitions-duplicate-identifier-typescript-fix/) indicates that the solution is either:

- Change `es6` to `es5` in `compilerOptions`'s lib property. This way TypeScript won’t include ES6 type definitions.
- Remove `core-js` from `node_modules`. This way TypeScript will use only its internal ES6 type definitions.

What I don't understand is why does `@types/core-js` then even exist, and when is it useful, since the compiler already ships with these definitions?

Comment: 2 years later I want a answer to this as well...